# Why are the OV and VO blocks of the CIS 1RDM zero?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density

I know the reduced density matrix has the form:
$$
\gamma(\alpha,\beta) = \langle\Psi_N|c^{\dagger}_{\alpha} c_{\beta}|\Psi_n \rangle
$$
but when $\Psi_N$ is the configuration interaction singles (CIS) wavefunction, why are the occupied-virtual (OV) and virtual-occupied (VO) subblocks zero?  I see multiple references state that it is due to Brillouins Theorem, but I don't entirely see that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think that the OV and VO blocks of the CIS density matrix are zero. We can calculate the whole thing quite easily. I'm going to adopt the conventional notation in which $p,q,r,s$ are generic MO orbitals indices, $i,j,k,l$ enumerate occupied MOs, and $a,b,c,d$ run over the unoccupied MOs. To facilitate writing some of the expressions, further define step functions $\chi(p)$ and $\pi(p)$ which are equal to 1 when when $p$ belongs to the occupied and unoccupied orbitals, respectively, and 0 otherwise.

As per your definition, the one-particle reduced density matrix (1PRDM) is

$\gamma_{q}^{p} = \langle \Psi_{\mathrm{CIS}} | X_p^+ X_q | \Psi_{\mathrm{CIS}} \rangle$,

where the CIS wave function using intermediate normalization is defined as

$|\Psi_{\mathrm{CIS}} \rangle = (1 + C_1) | \Phi \rangle$

with

$C_1 = \sum_{ai} c_{a}^{i} N[X_p^+ X_q]$

being the one-body particle-hole excitation operator responsible for generating singles out of the reference determinant $|\Phi\rangle$, here assumed to be the Hartree-Fock state. I'm using the notation $N[...]$ to denote the normal-ordered operator product with respect to the reference determinant.

Plugging in this definition, we get 4 contributions to the 1PRDM,

$\gamma_{q}^{p} = \langle \Phi | X_p^+ X_q | \Phi \rangle + \langle \Phi | C_1^+ X_p^+ X_q | \Phi \rangle + \langle \Phi | X_p^+ X_q C_1 | \Phi \rangle + \langle \Phi | C_1^+ X_p^+ X_q C_1 | \Phi \rangle$.

The first term is the Hartree-Fock density matrix and is equal to $\delta_{pq} \chi(p)$ (it has 1's along the diagonal of the OO block and 0's elsewhere).

The next two terms are the OV and VO blocks, respectively. Using Wick's Theorem or the diagrammatic method,

$\langle \Phi | C_1^+ X_p^+ X_q | \Phi \rangle = \sum_{ai} c_{i}^{a} \langle \Phi | N[X_i^+ X_a] X_p^+ X_q | \Phi \rangle = c_{q}^{p} \pi(p) \chi(q)$

and

$\langle \Phi | X_p^+ X_q C_1 | \Phi \rangle = \sum_{ai} c_{a}^{i} \langle \Phi | X_p^+ X_q N[X_a^+ X_i] | \Phi = c_{q}^{p} \chi(p) \pi(q)$.

Clearly, the OV and VO blocks are equal as they should be ($c_{a}^{i} = c_{i}^{a}$ for real orbitals) and non-zero since the CI singles excitation amplitudes are non-zero.

The last term, when expanded, results in

$\langle \Phi | C_1^+ X_p^+ X_q C_1 | \Phi \rangle = \sum_{abij} c_{i}^{a} c_{b}^{j} \langle \Phi | N[X_i^+ X_a] X_p^+ X_q N[X_b^+ X_j] | \Phi \rangle$.

There are two distinct ways to carry out the full contraction for this term which results in the VV and OO blocks. In the end, this becomes

$\sum_{abij} c_{i}^{a} c_{b}^{j} \langle \Phi | N[X_i^+ X_a] X_p^+ X_q N[X_b^+ X_j] | \Phi \rangle = \sum_{i} c_{i}^{p} c_{q}^{i} \pi(p) \pi(q) - 
\sum_{a} c_{q}^{a} c_{a}^{p} \chi(p) \chi(q)$,

where the first term is the VV block and the second term is the OO block.

Altogether,

$\gamma_{q}^{p} = \delta_{pq} \chi(p) + c_{q}^{p}(\pi(p)\chi(q) + \chi(p)\pi(q)) + \sum_{i} c_{i}^{p} c_{q}^{i} \pi(p)\pi(q) - \sum_{a} c_{q}^{a} c_{a}^{p} \chi(p) \chi(q)$,

which is a working formula for the 1PRDM matrix element for any given MO indices $p$ and $q$.

Furthermore, subtracting off the Hartree-Fock part results in the normal-ordered part of the 1PRDM, which is sometimes called $\Delta \gamma_{q}^{p}$, or

$(\gamma_{q}^{p})_N = \Delta \gamma_{q}^{p} = c_{q}^{p}(\pi(p)\chi(q) + \chi(p)\pi(q)) + \sum_{i} c_{i}^{p} c_{q}^{i} \pi(p)\pi(q) - \sum_{a} c_{q}^{a} c_{a}^{p} \chi(p) \chi(q)$.

Comment: Very nice answer! If you haven't come across it yet, you might also be interested in [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) which focuses on computational chemistry/materials.